# How to create a new instance of current instance?

Tags: haxe

I need to create a new instance of the current instance type, I tried:

```
var instance:Dynamic = Type.createInstance(Type.resolveClass(Type.getClassName(this)));
```

I get this error:

```
src/com/clientside/compoents/core/Component.hx:995: characters 84-88 : 
com.clientside.compoents.core.Component should be Class<Dynamic>
```

How would I create a new instance using Type.createInstance of current instance??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
  public function create():MyClass
{
    return Type.createInstance(Type.getClass(this),[]);
}
```

But i don't get why you would do that !!

Comment: It was late hour, I posted the question and went to sleep! thank you